# Using auto specifier in std::function and lambdas

Tags: c++, lambda, auto

I have a class named `Handler` which stores some lambdas. What I want to do is to have a `std::vector` of `std::function` that stores all my events, for example. I really can't figure out why lambdas doesn't work as I expected.

Here's the `handler.h`:

```
class Handler
{
public:
    Handler();
    ~Handler();

    void Register(const char* outcome, std::function<auto()> lambda);
    void Trigger(const char* outcome);

private:
    std::vector<int> identifier;
    std::vector<char*> outcome;
    std::vector<std::function<auto()>> func;
};
```

And `handler.cpp`:

```
Handler::Handler()
{
    //ctor stuff here
}


Handler::~Handler()
{
    this->func.clear();
    this->outcome.clear();
    this->identifier.clear();
    //...
}

void Handler::Register(const char* outcome, std::function<auto()> lambda)
{
    static int identifier = 0;
    identifier++;
    this->outcome.push_back((char*)outcome);
    this->identifier.push_back(identifier);
    this->func.push_back(lambda);
    //Sort outcome
}

void Handler::Trigger(const char * outcome)
{
    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < this->identifier.size(); i++)
    {
        if (!strcmp(outcome, this->outcome.at(i)))
            break;
    }
    this->func[i]();
}
```

However, if I specify lambdas in a `Handler::Register` it wont let me throwing `no suitable user-defined conversion from "lambda []void ()->void" to "std::function<auto()> exists`. In this example I use `void` return type but other types also error, I don't understand why can't the template from `std::function` deduce it out, if it is what's happening.

```
Handler* events = new Handler();

    events->Register("Up", [=]() -> void { //Error here!
        //do stuff
        //return something?
    });
```

Is there any other way to do this, like without overloading `Handler::Register`?

Comment: I'm amazed `std::function<auto()>` compiles at all

Comment: I don't think you can have a vector of std::functions each of them possibly of a different type. it would be like having a vector the would be able to store different kinds of objects.

Comment: @StoryTeller It doesn`t? I havent tested it at all since the compiler didn't bother with that.

Comment: this: `this->outcome.push_back((char*)outcome);` is just evil. It won't work and will just create headakes if you want to fix it. use `std::vector<std::string> outcome;` instead.

Comment: [No, it doesn't build](https://ideone.com/uA7K9v). And checking it was rather simple. You should always verify a construct you are new to, before hiding it in a bigger wall of code. Your entire approach fails.

Comment: @IlBeldus It was a fast scratch of code to start up the handler. Im moving on from ANSI-C myself so using somethings like string isn't very common for me. I realize casting `(char*)` on to a `const char*` is evil. Anyways it seems to be working for me. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: @StoryTeller I'm impressed... It seems like this approach would fail anyways then. I wasn't expecting this out of the question. Whoops...
So I guess I will need to make this with some different vectors for each type then

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`auto` is not a type, so `std::function<auto()>` is not a type either. From how you are using it, `std::function<void()>` is probably what you want.

There are other problems with your code, as noted in the comments, so I would change `Handler` to this

```
class Handler
{
public:
    Handler();
    // default ~Handler is fine

    void Register(std::string outcome, std::function<void()> lambda);
    void Trigger(const std::string & outcome outcome) const;
    void Trigger(std::size_t index) const;

private:
    using Outcomes = std::map<std::string, std::function<void()>/*, custom string comparator ?*/>;
    std::vector<Outcomes::iterator> identifier;
    Outcomes outcomes;
};

void Handler::Register(std::string outcome, std::function<void()> func)
{
    auto emplaced = outcomes.emplace(std::move(outcome), std::move(func));
    identifier.push_back(emplaced.first);
}

void Handler::Trigger(const std::string & outcome) const
{
    outcomes.at(outcome)();
}

void Handler::Trigger(std::size_t index) const
{
    identifier[index]->second();
}
```

Comment: `identifier`  seems superfluous. and some const reference are missing.

Comment: @Jarod42 I'm assuming OP was using `identifier` as an insertion-order index in elided code